# Is it better to populate variables using SET or SELECT?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance, query-performance

What is the better way (with regards to performance) to set a value to variable?

1. By `SET` command:

   ```
   DECLARE @VarString nvarchar(max);
   SET @VarString = 'john doe';
   SELECT @VarString;
   ```
2. By `SELECT` command:

   ```
   DECLARE @VarString nvarchar(max);
   SELECT @VarString = 'john doe';
   SELECT @VarString;
   ```

Comment: Using SELECT is not semantic, but i'm curious to know if it's faster than SET.

Comment: You may want to look into this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189588/speed-of-select-vs-set-in-t-sql

Comment: @RafaelKassner - `SELECT` is faster when [assigning values to multiple variables at once](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1888/when-to-use-set-vs-select-when-assigning-values-to-variables-in-sql-server/). Otherwise, the performance difference is negligible.

Comment: @SQLLearner - That report gives inconclusive results. First the poster states that `SET` is faster, then half-way down he adds: "Oddly, if you crank the number of runs up to say, 10, the `SET` begins to lag behind."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't pick one or the other strictly for performance.

Pick based on what fits your style and development needs, as is advised in the conclusion to [this excellent comparison between `SELECT` and `SET`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1888/when-to-use-set-vs-select-when-assigning-values-to-variables-in-sql-server/) (emphasis and minor formatting added):

> **Best practice suggests not to stick to one method.** Depending on the
>   scenario you may want to use both `SET` or `SELECT`.
>
> **Following are few scenarios for using `SET`:**
>
> - If you are required to assign a single value directly to variable and no query is involved to fetch value
> - NULL assignments are expected (`NULL` returned in result set)
> - Standards are meant to be follow for any planned migration
> - Non scalar results are expected and are required to be handled
>
> **Using `SELECT` is efficient and flexible in the following few cases:**
>
> - Multiple variables are being populated by assigning values directly
> - Multiple variables are being populated by single source (table , view)
> - Less coding for assigning multiple variables
> - Use this if you need to get `@@ROWCOUNT` and `@ERROR` for last statement executed

Answer (score 4):

I think the consensus is there's a negligible performance difference between the two (with `SET` being faster). But if you are like me, I'd use `SET` where appropriate for readability purposes. The next guy who will maintain your code will thank you for that ;-)

Comment: Can you post benchmarks proving that SET is faster?

Comment: Alex, please take a look at this as an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189588/speed-of-select-vs-set-in-t-sql

Comment: Marlon, that report gives inconclusive results. Note that half-way down the poster notes that: "Oddly, if you crank the number of runs up to say, 10, the SET begins to lag behind."

Comment: That's the reason why my answer is leaning towards "readability purposes". The use case scenario in your answer are great points.

Answer (score 2):

I always use SET unless I am populating multiple variables from the result set of 1 query. That way, by using SELECT we only query the table once.